# How to get double return value of atof() function (from msvcrt.dll) in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, 64-bit, fasm

I want to convert string representing floating point number to double (64bit ieee754) and store the result of conversion in the register RAX from assembly (using FASM). First of all I included library to my main.asm:

```
atof: jmp [imp_atof]
section '.idata' import data readable writeable
library kernel32,'KERNEL32.DLL',\
  user32,'USER32.DLL', \
  msvcrt, "MSVCRT.DLL"
include "macro\import64.inc"
   import msvcrt, \
   imp_atof, 'atof'
```

Next step is to call atof() in code:

```
push _buffer ;this is string buffer holding float number
call atof
```

After that something strange happening and I cannot understand what exactly. For example we need to convert **-2309.12E-15**. Result must be: **BD844FAD0D676443**. High result of the covert operation is right. It is stored in r8 register:

**r8 = 00000000BD844FAD**

But no one register store Low result. After debugging code calls I found that somewhere low result written to EAX register (**000000000D676443**) and then disappear. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Parameters don't get passed on the stack in 64bit land,  but in registers.  Not sure what registers are used on Windows so consult Wikipedia for x86-64 calling conventions.

Comment: Thanks, @cremno showed that it is stored in xmm0. But interesting that converted values appears at registers (eax, r8d) and also in YMM0I0 in one function call. I think there is must exist some performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows x64 the return value in this case is in `XMM0`. From the [calling convention documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7572ztz4.aspx) on MSDN:

> Non-scalar types including floats, doubles, and vector types such as __m128, __m128i, and __m128d are returned in XMM0.